# Changing a string to match a char array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm very inexperienced in programming, so bear with me.

I have to write a class that mimics some attributes of the String class. In this particular method, I have to take a char array and get a string to match it.

This is what I have so far:

```
1 char[] word = new char[80];
2 int wordLength = word.length;    
3
4 public String getString () {
5      String s;
6      s.length() = word.length;
7      for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
8           s.charAt(i) = word[i];
9      }
10     return s; 
11 }
```

I should mention that the char array is null here, but in the main method, values are assigned to it.

This is the error I'm getting at lines 6 and 8:

```
The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
```

I have no idea why it isn't recognizing String s as a variable.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if you are allowed to use that, but you can create a String from a char array like this:

```
String s = new String(charArray);
```

Now to your code:

```
String s;
s.length() = word.length;
```

Two problems here, first s is not initialized, before you can do anyting with it, you need to assign a value to it:

```
String s = new String();
```

Since this creates a completely new `String` it is better to use the following code, since Strings are chached:

```
String s = "";
```

Next String is a immutable class, which means you can't change any attributes, once it is created. Plus s.length() returns an int value and NO pointer/reference, which means you can't assign a new value to it like that. Same goes with

```
s.charAt(i) = word[i];
```

its simply not possible.

To create a `String` char by char you can do something like this:

```
String s = "";
for (char c : charArray)
{
    s += c;
}
```

Note that `s += c` creates a new `String` each time.

Better to use a `StringBuilder`:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : charArray)
{
    s.append(c);
}
s.toString();
```

And again, you could do that in one line:

```
String s = new StringBuilder().append(charArray).toString();
```

Comment: `String s = new String();` Please prefer `String s = "";` instead :).

Comment: Yeah :). But you have to admit that creating a String like the OP wants to create it is quite inefficient to begin with.

Comment: Correct, but since you like to show him better approaches, you can also do this by avoiding the empty String constructor :D.

Answer (score 4):

The error is here:

```
s.length() = word.length;
s.charAt(i) = word[i];    // same here
```

You are trying to assign the length to the return value of length method.

Also note that, `String s`, is uninitialized.

The simplest form of `getString()` will look like this:

```
public String getString () {
  String s = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    s = s + word[i];
  }
  return s;
}
```

It would be better to use `StringBuilder` instead of string concatenation.

```
public String getString () {
  StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    builder.append(word[i]);
  }
  return builder.toString();
}
```

Comment: *"Also note that, String s, is uninitialized. so it will throw NPE at runtime."* This is not correct. Please check again ;P.

Comment: `s.charAt(i)` this is what i meant.

Comment: So you think that `s.charAt(i)` will throw an exception during runtime, even though this code doesn't compile? How is that possible? (I hope this "hint" will help you to notice, that "it will throw NullPointerException at runtime" is wrong).

Comment: @Tom When you fix all the compilation issues. I am trying to gives heads up.

Comment: A heads up with wrong stuff? When a local variable isn't initialized, then the code won't compile. You need to initialize it and then ... well, it isn't uninitialized anymore. And it will only throw the mentioned exception if one inizializes it with `null` which would be rather ... lame.

Comment: @Tom I tried to address first compilation issue, once these are fixed then I mentioned about the uninitialized object. I think that is fair. I don't see lame in that.

Comment: *"I don't see lame in that."* Because you don't understand what I mean. An uninitilized local variable is a compile time error. So writing *"String s, is uninitialized. so it will throw NullPointerException at runtime"* is wrong, in any case. If OP inizializes the variable, then there is only one chance he will get the exception you've mentioned: by initializing `s` with `null`. Doing this is lame. I have no idea why you think I meant your note.

Answer (score 3):

The error is exactly what it says on the tin. The left hand side of an assignment must be a variable.

A variable is a basically a container which can hold values, and you can assign values to such containers. For example, in the line

```
int wordLength = word.length;
```

You define such a container, which you name wordLength, and you assign the value inside the class variable `word.length`. Here, `word.length` is a value representing the length of the character array.

Anyways, when try this

```
s.length() = word.length;
```

then keep in mind that `s.length()` is a method, which returns a value, not a variable, so, you are trying to assign a value to a value. Which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

`s.charAt(i)` and `s.length()` only return values.

You need only this:

```
String s = String.valueOf(word);
```

Answer (score 2):

Calling the method length returns you a value. The error of your code is that you're trying to assign a value to a method that returns a value which makes no sense. 
Second of all, for performance purposes,  you would be better off using the StringBuilder class to build your string from your char array. All you need to do at creation is specify the length with the help of word.length() then inside your for loop, you call the method append which will add the content to the builder. Finally, you return the string builder string using the method toString().

```
public String getString () {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word.length);
      for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
           sb.append(word[i].toString());// you must give a string to the string builder
      }
     return sb.toString(); 
 }
```

Comment: More on the StringBuilder API when you take a peak at the following link : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Answer (score 1):

```
s.length() = word.length;
```

You cannot do that. The `length()` method is access method that provide a `String` size. It isn't a variable. Pay attention:

```
int variable; // the non-initialized variable
s.length(); // the method invoking
variable = s.length(); // the variable initializing
```

---

You may use the following snippet:

```
String s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    s += word[i]; // Both "+" and "+=" operators are a bad practice
}
return s;
```

A better practice is to use `StringBuilder` to concatenate chars to one `String`:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    builder.append(word[i]);
}
return builder.toString();
```

Comment: Don't you have to specify its length(StringBuilder) cause originally, it starts with a size of 16 characters..

Comment: @KevinAvignon *"it starts with a size of 16 characters"*: A `StringBuilder` expands the underlying array if necessary. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: was not sure about that ooops ! Used to specify a size to the builder !

Comment: @KevinAvignon, It doesn't have a such important sense in this case.

Comment: @KevinAvignon You can do that if you already know the final size of the array (more or less). This avoids increasing the array size, which costs time.